# Extending diagonalization in numpy to more than 2 dimensions

Tags: numpy, matrix

I have a vector

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> v = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

in numpy. One uses `np.diag` to create a diagonal matrix from this vector, to get the following.

```
[[1, 0, 0],
[0, 2, 0],
[0, 0, 3]]
```

However, as noted in the [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html), the `np.diag` function only works with 1D and 2D matrices.
What if the elements of `v` themselves are `n x m` np arrays? How to diagonalize that array expediently and fast? Come on, the point is that instead of the 0's we'd have `n x m` sized zero matrices.

This is what I want:

```
Q = [Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5]
```

Where `Q_i` are `n x m` matrices, i.e., `Q_i.shape = (n, m)`. Therefore, the shape of `Q` is `(5, n, m)`.
Now I want a diagonal matrix:

```
Q_diag =
[[Q1 0 0 0 0]
[0 Q2 0 0 0]
[0 0 Q3 0 0]
[0 0 0 Q4 0]
[0 0 0 0 Q5]]
```

And the `0`'s are in fact themselves `n x m` matrices, that is, have the shape `(n, m)`. So in all the shape of Q_diag would be Q_diag.shape = (5, 5, n, m).

Comment: You just asked this a few minutes ago.  OK  it was marked as `duplicate`, but you should have raised your objects in comments there, rather than repeat the same question.  You need to explain more clearly what you need.  Show exactly what you expect.  We can't help with the fast if we don't know what the slow is.

Comment: We want to diagonalize the elements of a vector, and the elements are themselves numpy arrays. The np.diag doesn't let you do that. And yeah, it shouldn't use Python's for loops since those are inefficient, 300x slower than any native numpy implementation we come up with.

Comment: I'm still waiting for a working example - even if it uses those horrible loops.